# Not able to find any locator with respect to another locator in karate feature file

Tags: karate

I have defined some locator in common file and i want to find few locators with the help of already defined locator(bcs these two are related). Suppos i define inside locator.json file:

```
 { mainPage 
        {"firstLocator": "//div[text()='a']
          "secondLocator": "//div[text()='b']
         "image": "//img"
     }
 }
```

Now in my feature file i want to do so that it will click on respective image of first and second locator:

```
* click(mainPage.firstLocator.img)
* click(mainPage.secondLocator.img)
```

I do have many scenarios in which i would need to find one locator available as children of many object, thus i want to define them separately and concatenate in feature file itself. this will save me defining all children locators in common file

Comment: sorry I think this is over-engineering, I will stand back and let others answer this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#locator-lookup